# foreach loop not working

Tags: php

I'm trying to use a foreach loop to search for word in $_POST, but it doesn't work? Help is preciated.

```
$unsafeWords = array('content-typ','bcc','cc');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    foreach ($unsafeWords as $value) {
        $_POST = str_ireplace($value, "", $input) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: is this for email sending script?

Comment: The content of $_POST comes from a form with fields like 'name', 'email' and 'message' and I want to check it before sending it. Is it secure enough to just search the input from 'email' or all inputs like I have done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't overwrite the $_POST array with a string

```
$unsafeWords = array('content-typ','bcc','cc');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    foreach ($unsafeWords as $value) {
        $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace($value, "", $input) ;
    }
}
```

though I dislike overwriting the original $_POST array and would prefer to build a new array of cleaned values

Note that you don't need to loop the $unsafeWords array, but can pass an it as an array directly to str_ireplace()

**EDIT**

Example of using the $unsafeWords array as an argument for str_ireplace() rather than looping through it with foreach() and calling str_ireplace() for each entry.

```
$unsafeWords = array('content-type','bcc','cc');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace($unsafeWords, "", $input) ;
}
```

and you're not replacing with a space, you're replacing with an empty string (effectively removing the unsafe strings from your $_POST vars)

**EDIT 2**

> I guess it's OK to put this inside the
>   foreach loop as well?

Not quite... if you're just adding it as an extra line within the loop, you'll overwrite your previous substitutions.
Do it as:

```
$unsafeWords = array('content-type','bcc','cc');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace($unsafeWords, "", filter_var($input, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED)) ;
}
```

Comment: "Note that you don't need to loop the $unsafeWords array, but can pass an it as an array directly to str_ireplace()" How would it be done? I changed to $_POST[$key] but it doesn't work correct! 'bcc' only removes 'cc' and content-type(I typed wrong in the my question) still in the array and not replaced by space!?

Comment: I guess it's OK to put this inside the foreach loop as well? $_POST[$key] = (filter_var($input,  FILTER_SANITIZE_STRIPPED)); Would my form be secure enough? Or do you have any other advice? Do I need to trim and change the htmlencodings? Thanks!

Comment: @user still multiple "To:" headers could be injected. your silly "unsafewords" approach seems utterly unsafe

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to overwrite `$_POST` (which is an array) with string values. The correct way is this:

```
foreach ($_POST as &$input) {
    $input = str_ireplace($unsafeWords, array(), $input) ;
}
```

The above code also takes advantage of a couple other features (`foreach` with a reference as loop variable, `str_ireplace` accepting arrays) to be much shorter.

Comment: what does the '&' do before the $input?

Comment: It makes $input a reference, which makes any changes to the value of $input actually change the value in $_POST. Otherwise you'd just be changing a copied value.

Answer (score 1):

Not completely clear what you're asking but this:

```
 $_POST = str_ireplace($value, "", $input) ;
```

definitely won't do what you expect. You probably want:

```
 $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace($value, "", $input) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead (missing $key at the assignment)

```
$unsafeWords = array('content-typ','bcc','cc');
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input) {
    foreach ($unsafeWords as $value) {
        $_POST[$key] = str_ireplace($value, "", $input) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside form that foreach problem, it seems **very insufficient** validation in terms of mail injection protection.

For the email field I'd use some regexp-based or filter_var() solution.
For the name and subject fields I'd suggest to encode it according to RFC rules.

So, I believe that safe code could be (in case of utf-8 encoded email):

```
if ($email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
  $subject = "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['subject'])."?=";
  $from    = "From: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($_POST['name'])."?= <$email>\r\n";
  $message = str_replace("\n.", "\n .", $_POST['text']);
  mail('me@example.com',$subject,$message,$from);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to remove indexes from the $_POST array that are specified in the $unsafeWords, then you went on with the wrong approach. Use unset() function to remove the index you don't want or simply set it to

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $input)
{
    if(in_array($input, $unsafeWords)
    {
        $_POST[$key] = null; // or $_POST[$key] = '' or unset($_POST[$key]
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to serach for the words 'content'type', 'bcc', 'cc' and just replace those word inside the strings of each input. I don't want to erase the hole string or the index

Comment: What you originally did was replace the current entry with an empty string. If you take a few seconds to look at the code I provided, you'll notice what I put inside the comments which is exactly what you were doing, except for each entry in $_POST I didn't loop trough $unsafeWords. It's not hard to make changes to the code to make it do what you want.